# You have an error in your SQL syntax when i have single comas and |

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to sql, trying to insert values in my table

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, ALL||test > test's done> test's done again's done||test > test's done> test's done again's done 2,new);
```

the second field is of type varchar 4000 charaters.

I'm getting the following error :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ALL||test > test's done> test's done again's done||test > test's done> test's done again's done 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put strings in quotes.  And then you need to escape the single quotes.  So this looks like:

```
INSERT INTO table1
    VALUES (1, 
            'ALL||test > test''s done > test''s done again''s done||test > test''s done> test''s done again''s done 2',
            'new'
           );
```

The double single quotes turns into a single single quote in a string.

Note that you should be listing the column names in the insert, such as:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3) . . .
```

Comment: Some RDBMS (Sybase, for sure) allow you to make " an alternative to ' so you can " your string containing '.  (Usually " is for enclosing key words and column names with embedded blanks, dots, etc..)